# Powershell: Place all files in a specified directory into separate, uniquely named subdirectories

Tags: windows, powershell, mkdir, get-childitem

I have an existing directory, let's say "C:\Users\Test" that contains files (with various extensions) and subdirectories. I'm trying to write a Powershell script to that will put each file in "C:\Users\Test" into a uniquely named subdirectory, such as "\001", "\002", etc., while ignoring any existing subdirectories and files therein. Example:

Before running script:

```
C:\Users\Test\ABC.xlsx
C:\Users\Test\QRS.pdf
C:\Users\Test\XYZ.docx
C:\Users\Test\Folder1\TUV.gif
```

After running script:

```
C:\Users\Test\001\ABC.xlsx
C:\Users\Test\002\QRS.pdf
C:\Users\Test\003\XYZ.docx
C:\Users\Test\Folder1\TUV.gif
```

Note:
Names, extensions, and number of files will vary each time the script is run on a batch of files. The order in which files are placed into the new numbered subdirectories is not important, just that each subdirectory has a short, unique name. I have another script that will apply a consistent sequential naming convention for all subdirectories, but first I need to get all files into separate folders while maintaining their native file names.

This is where I'm at so far:

```js
$id = 1
Get-ChildItem | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}| % {
MD ($_.root +($id++).tostring('000'));
MV $_ -Destination ($_.root +(001+n))
}
```

The MD expression successfully creates the subdirectories, but I not sure how to write the MV expression to actually move the files into them. I've written (001+n) to illustrate the concept I'm going for, where n would increment from 0 to the total number of files. Or perhaps an entirely different approach is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = 1
Get-ChildItem C:\Test\ -file  | % {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Test -Name $id.tostring('000')
    Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination C:\Test\$($id.tostring('000'))
    $id++
}
```

`Move-Item` is what you were looking for.

Comment: He has MV (alias of move-item) in his script. Something else is wrong with it. Regardless, I'd have done the exact same as you did here. :) Much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think I figured it out. Running the following scripts sequentially produces the desired result. The trick was resetting the $id increment when running the MV expression. This can probably be improved though, so let me know if you have a better way! Edited: @ArcSet has provided a better answer in a single script! Thank you!

```js
$id = 1
Get-ChildItem | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}| % {
MD ($_.root +($id++).tostring('000'))
}
```

```js
$id = 1
Get-ChildItem | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}| % {
MV $_ -Destination($_.root +($id++).tostring('000'))
}
```